# I am trying to print the highest odd number but giving my y and z value the highest number (even if its even) creates an issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the highest odd number but giving my y and z value the highest number (even if its even) creates an issue??

```
x,y,z = 13, 14, 10

if x%2 != 0 or y%2 != 0 or z%2 != 0:
    if x > y and x > z and x%2 != 0:
        print(x)
    elif y > z and y%2 != 0:
        print(y)
    elif z%2 != 0:
        print(z)

else:
    print('None of them are odd!')
```

Comment: The more complex the code, the more space for messing up. Simpler is better: `max(x for x in [13, 14, 10] if x % 2)` (and rescue `ValueError` for when none are odd).

Comment: The `!= 0` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler if you just iterate over the values, rejecting those that are even and remembering the largest odd one so far.

```
largest = None 
for n in [x, y, z]:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        continue
    if largest is None or n > largest:
        largest = n

if largest is None:
    print("None are odd")
else:
    print(largest)
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback! The continue statement will do wonders for my remaining problems!

Comment: FYI, [Eriall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979170/1126841) and Amadan's answer is probably best; I wrote this answer under the impression that you didn't want to use the `max` function that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Its easier to just use a list instead of assigning each value to a variable, but if you need to keep the x, y, z then use:

```
x,y,z = 13, 14, 10
try:
    print(max(i for i in [x, y, z] if i % 2))
except ValueError:
    print("None Are Odd")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a list along with set comprehension, something like this below:

```
x,y,z = 13, 15, 10
odd = {x for x in [x,y,z] if x%2}
if odd:
    print(max(odd))
else:
    print("None of them are odd!")
```